# How to run script inside ajax page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mootools

On clicking the links am sending the ajax call to get the response, am able to get the correct response but the script tag inside the response page is not working. how to make it run

This is HTML PAGE

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxgetter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<h1>ajax block container</h1>

<div id="container">
    <div id="tab_wrapper">
        <ul id="tab_list" >
            <li>
             <a href="#" id="firstelement" onclick="ajaxenabled('elements/firstelement.html','firstelement','content_tab')">Number 1 </a>               
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#" id="secondelement" onclick="ajaxenabled('elements/secondelement.html','secondelement','content_tab')">Number 2</a>
              <br/><br/><br/>
              </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="content_tab">

</div>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The javascript code

```
function ajaxenabled(url,param,id)
{
    var page_request = false    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e){
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e){}
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
        page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(param!=null)
            {
                loadpage(page_request, param,id);
            }
            if(param==null)
            {
                loadpage(page_request,'',id);

            }
        }
        page_request.open('GET', url, true);
        page_request.send(null);
}


function loadpage(page_request,param,id){

    var getblock=document.getElementById(id);

    if(page_request.status==200) {
        getblock.style.display='block';
        getblock.innerHTML=page_request.responseText;

    if(param!=null)
        {
            //alert("showed");
        }   

    }

}
```

Response Page " firstelement.html "

```
<h1>First Element having ajax call</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("testing the simple function");
</script>
```

The Alert present inside Script tab inside the  firstelement.html is not triggered ,

Comment: you run mootools but don't use the Request class. Request has a special option `evalScripts: true|false` - which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You should move that script from inside the HTML file to a .js file and call that script after you have successfully finished the ajax call.
Your HTML file will be:

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxgetter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE_HERE.js"></script>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>

  <h1>ajax block container</h1>

  .
  .
  .
```

You will of course move the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("testing the simple function");
</script>
```

into a .js file you place inside the "js" directory. Remember to do it as a method you can call so the .js file will have something like this

```
function afterAjaxSuccess(){
    alert("testing the simple function");
  }
```

and then in your html file you update your loadpage method like this:

```
function loadpage(page_request,param,id){

var getblock=document.getElementById(id);

if(page_request.status==200) {
    getblock.style.display='block';
    getblock.innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
    afterAjaxSuccess();                             //updated line here

if(param!=null)
    {
        //alert("showed");
    }   

}
```

}

and your HTML page becomes

```
<h1>First Element having ajax call</h1>
```

without any script

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to achieve it?

Comment: Thnx for the answer , i will try and let you know

Comment: It gives alert more than once depending on the number of list i have

Comment: yes, if you make multiple ajax call it will trigger that script multiple times. consider calling the method inside the script only after you have loaded the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

I just use mootools [Request.HTML](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML) it will evaluate all the script tags in the returned page and replace the html in an element if the update is set in the options.